# SQL Query for display the all month of last three years

Tags: sql

```
Year Month
2020 1
2020 2
2020 3
   .
   .
   . 12
2019 1
2019 2
2019 3
  .  
  .
  .
     12
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Use a recursive cte.